# Texture paint mode - the brush paints some weird purple thing instead of color

Tags: texture-painting, normal-map, blend-modes

Hi i've finished my low poly of the sculp i made and projected the normals onto it.
Later i tried to paint on it but when i do this weird normal map looking texture with balls and springs on it.
It never happened to me before, what causes this?[image]

[EDIT] turns out it fixes itself if you just delete your current brush and recreate it again

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the OP picture, the OP was using the Normal Map image as a brush texture that is automatically set to Tiled when first used, and that is why it was 'fixed' by deleting the brush and starting over. Could have been easily fixed by disconnecting the Normal Map texture from the brush texture.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by deleting the set of brushes and making a new one.